# Checking what subclass the object is in, then running a method in that subclass - Java

Tags: java, abstract

I have an abstract class called Policy, and two subclasses DepreciablePolicy and ExpirablePolicy
I have an array of Policy, policies[]

I want to check what subclass my object is in (if it's a Policy, DepreciablePolicy or ExpirablePolicy)

I did this by using this if statement.

```
if (this.policies[polNum] instanceof DepreciablePolicy){
```

For each type of subclass, there is a different method I have to run.
Only problem is that I'm only able to use the Policy methods, but not the subclass methods or constructors.
Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is inheritance done the wrong way. The whole point of polymorphism is that your code doesn't care which subclass an object is. Anything you need to do should be expressed through the Policy, which should really be an interface. Your code should interact with a Policy based on that interface, and the subclasses choose how to react.

That being said, you're probably looking for simple down-casting:

```
DepreciablePolicy d = (DepreciablePolicy) policy;
```

This is nothing better than a poor bandage on a bad design, though.

Comment: I agree - as specified, the answer to the question is obviously using a type cast - but likely a redesign is better.

Comment: Thank you, I'll be using this method until I figure out the right way

Answer (score 5):

> For each type of subclass, there is a different method I have to run.

Then you've misdesigned it. Define an abstract method in Policy, have all the derived classes implement it according to their own requirements. Then just call the method.

Comment: I'm just starting to use Abstract. I'd like to redesign my project. I tried googling how to implement derived classes and nothing much came up. Could you help me out on how I would do this?

Comment: @user1692517: You should re-Google this perhaps using different search terms as this has been very well discussed in many tutorials. If you get stuck doing it, don't ask folks to re-write full tutorials, but instead tell us *exactly* where you might be stuck and show code.